# How can I fix mpv from not showing full image?

Tags: linux, mpv

I use `mpv` as my image viewer. But sometimes, when I open an image, the whole image does not display. I have to press `r` to reload it. When I do so, the image gets displayed properly.

Is there anything I have to put into my config file for it to work properly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to my `mpv.conf` to make it work:

```
# If the current file is an image, keep
# it open forever
image-display-duration=inf

# Loop files in case of webms or gifs
loop-file=inf

scale=spline36
cscale=spline36
dscale=mitchell
dither-depth=auto
correct-downscaling
sigmoid-upscaling
```

Source: https://github.com/occivink/mpv-image-viewer/blob/master/mpv.conf